# websocket stops working after about 55 seconds

Tags: python, c#, websocket

Sometimes it crashes after 54 seconds, sometimes 56 seconds. Output looks like:

```
Server started. Listening for incoming connections...
55 Received message: hello server
1/12/2023 7:38:25 AM|Fatal|WebSocket.<startReceiving>b__176_2|System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
                           Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.
                              at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                              at WebSocketSharp.Ext.<>c__DisplayClass48_0.<ReadBytesAsync>b__0(IAsyncResult ar)
```

I tried to add a try/catch block but I am not sure where the error is happening. I am running a websocketsharp server in c# and sending it sample data via python:

C# SERVER CODE:

```
using System;
using WebSocketSharp;
using WebSocketSharp.Server;

public class Echo : WebSocketBehavior
{
    protected override void OnMessage(MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        try {
            Console.WriteLine("Received message: " + e.Data);
            Sessions.Broadcast(e.Data);
        }
        catch{
            Console.WriteLine("bad happened");
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var wssv = new WebSocketServer(8081);
        wssv.AddWebSocketService<Echo>("/Echo");
        wssv.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Server started. Listening for incoming connections...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        wssv.Stop();
    }
}
```

PYTHON CLIENT CODE:

```
import time
import websocket


def send_words(ws,words):
    data = words
    ws.send(data)


ws = websocket.create_connection("ws://localhost:8081/Echo")


while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    data = "hello server"
    send_words(ws,data)
```

Answer (score 0):

apparently its a websocket-sharp specific issue. You just have to add

```
wssv.KeepClean = false;
```

before

```
wssv.Start();
```